# EoM of a pendulum with two suspended X(Y) tables in 2D and horizontal moving pivot point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

The system I'm working on can be simplified to the system displayed in the figure below. This system consists of a pendulum where the pivot point is horizontally driven with a sinusoidal function. The two masses at the end of pendulum can be moved over the links on which they are placed. In reality the location of both masses are controlled and can be adjusted during the swinging of the pendulum. For simplicity the links can be assumed to have no mass. The goal of the system is to keep $m_1$ as close as possible to its initial x-coordinate by moving $m_2$ for compensation purposes.

I want to derive the equations of motion (EoM) for this system so that this system can be used in simulations. Literature can be found on a simple pendulum with a horizontally moving support, but this system adds the variables $r_1$ and $r_2$ which vary in time.

I've tried using the Lagrangian for solving the equations of motion, but was not successful as not only the variables $t$ and $\theta$ are present, but also $r_1$ and $r_2$. How can I approach this problem?

[image]

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Also, I have taken the liberty to [resize your images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/) to improve readability. Feel free to rollback if you wish. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r_1$ and $r_2$ are known (or "controllable") functions of time, then you just include them in the Lagrangian as functions of time.  They don't have equations of motion of their own, but the Euler-Lagrange equations will still work.

As a simpler example, if you had a simple pendulum with a length $l$ that was a known function of time $l(t)$, the Lagrangian would be
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} m \left(\dot{l}^2 + l^2 \dot{\phi}^2\right) + m g l(t) \cos \phi
$$
and the equation of motion for $\phi$ would then be
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}} \right) &=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} \\
\frac{d}{dt} \left( m l^2 \dot{\phi} \right) &= - m g l \sin \phi \\
 l^2 \ddot{\phi} + 2 l \dot{l} \dot{\phi}&= - g l \sin \phi \\
\end{align*}
You could then (in principle) solve this ODE for $\phi(t)$ given a known "length function" $l(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this problem, like any other in dynamics.

1. Establish the important quantities (DOFs) to completely describe the state of the device at any instant.
2. Establish the kinematics by completely describing the position, velocity and acceleration of *each* body as a function of the DOFs and their derivatives.
3. Apply the equations of motion, being Lagrangian or Newton-Euler to relate applied and connection forces to the motion of each body. This relates the connection forces to the motion.
4. Each joint might be free or powered, and there are generalized forces $Q$ that describe them. Use the kinematic relationships and the summation of power $P_{\rm out} = P_{\rm in} + P_{\rm motor}$ at each joint to describe them.
5. Form a linear system of equations to be solved as needed in the form of $$ Q = {\bf M} \,\ddot{q} + \boldsymbol{c}(q,\,\dot{q}) $$ where $q$ are the DOF, $\dot{q}$ the DOF speeds, $\ddot{q}$ the DOF accelerations, $\bf M$ the mass matrix, $Q$ the generalized forces for the system.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You can use the EoM that @Michael Seifert wrote if you "start"  with  the center of mass
position which is:

\begin{align*}
 &\mathbf{R}_{\text{CM}}=\frac{1}{m_1+m_2}\left(
-m_1 \,\begin{bmatrix}
   r_1(t) \\
   (l_1+l_2) \\
 \end{bmatrix}+
 m_2 \,\begin{bmatrix}
   r_2(t) \\
   -l_1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}\right)\\\\
 &\text{thus the pendulum length is:}\\
 &l(t)=\left(\mathbf{R}_{\text{CM}}\cdot \mathbf{R}_{\text{CM}}\right)^{1/2}\quad,
 \dot{l}=\frac{\mathbf{\dot{R}}_{\text{CM}}\cdot\,\mathbf{R}_{\text{CM}}}{l(t)}
\end{align*}

with the  "moving pivot point"  you have to add to the EoM

$$l(t)\,\cos(\theta)\frac{d^2 x(t)}{dt^2}\quad, x(t)=A\,\cos(\omega\,t)$$